# How to convert regular grammar with recursion and alternations into regular expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, compiler-construction

A grammar is regular if it is either right-linear or left-linear. [This tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/17-regex-grammars/#reading_17_regular_expressions_grammars) claims that because of that it has the special property:

> A regular grammar has a special property: by substituting every
> nonterminal (except the root one) with its righthand side, you can
> reduce it down to a single production for the root, with only
> terminals and operators on the right-hand side... The reduced
> expression of terminals and operators can be written in an even more
> compact form, called a regular expression

So I've decided to test that idea and convert the regular [EcmaScript grammar for IdentifierName](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierName) into regular expressions:

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName  IdentifierPart
```

Suppose `IdentifierStart` and `IdentifierPart` are limited to the following:

```
IdentifierStart ::       IdentifierPart ::
    A                        A                 
    B                        C
    C                        &
    $                    
    _
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed since the grammar for `IdentifierName` has both recursion and alternation. Any help?

I'm more interested in the approach rather than in finding the resulting regexp which as @Bergi showed is `[ABC$_][AC&]*`.

Comment: An IdentifierName is either an IdentifierName followed by an IdentifierPart, or an IdentifierStart, if IdentifierStart is S and IdentifierPart is P, then some legal IdentifierNames are S, SP, SPP, and so on... IE an S followed by some number of Ps. can you think of a regex to fit that?

Comment: Just `[ABC$_][AC&]*`

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, but I'm more interested in the approach of replacement rather then the regexp itself. Or is the example too simplistic so that it's possible to come up with the regexp without following the approach?

Comment: @M.Aroosi, thanks, please see [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894973/how-to-convert-regural-grammar-with-recursion-and-alternations-into-regural-expr#comment80737798_46894973)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is using some non-standard (and surprisingly implicit) definitions.

First of all they use repetition operators in their grammar as they might be found in regular expressions or EBNF. Then they *implicitly* define a regular grammar to be one that only uses those repetition operators and no recursion. Given that, it's trivial to turn a "regular grammar" into a regex by just inlining all the non-terminals. But by that definition the JS spec's grammar for identifiers is not regular because it contains recursion. So before you could inline everything, you'd first need to replace the recursion with repetition operators.

However this isn't the standard definition of what a regular grammar is. The standard definition is as you said: a grammar is regular if it's either left-linear or right-linear - that is if only the left-most item of a production is a non-terminal or if only the right-most one is. Repetition operators don't exist in the usual definition of a formal grammar.

Now these regular grammars can also be converted to regular expressions, but not by merely applying the method described in the tutorial. One way would be to convert the grammar to a finite automaton and then apply the algorithm described in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2389/46) for example.

However in practice, when doing the conversion by hand (rather than writing a program to do it) the easiest and most common way to perform the conversion is to think about what language the grammar describes (in this case "the language of all words that start with an IdentifierStart symbol and then contain 0 or more IdentifierPart symbols") and then come up with a regular expression that expresses that language (a.k.a. the "look really hard at the problem until you see the solution"-algorithm).

Comment: thanks, so would that algorithm work: 1) replace the recursion with repetition operators and then 2) substitute every nonterminal (except the root one) with its righthand side? or is the first part really not trivial by applying mechanical approach?

Comment: also I wrote  _A grammar is regular if it is either right-linear or left-linear. This tutorial claims that **because of that**..._. So it seems that it's not because of that the replacement algorithm will work, but because of the repetition operator?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Yes, that algorithm would work, but "replace the recursion with repetition operators" is a decidedly non-trivial step in the general case. And yes to your second comment as well: the replacement algorithm works because they defined regular grammars not as left-linear or right-linear grammars (which would be the usual definition), but as grammars that only use repetition operators instead of recursion.